# C# skip rest of if statement if inner if is true

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

my code is as follows:

```
public void Method()
{
    if (flagIsUp)
    {
         if (x = 1)
            code here;

         if (y = 2)
            code here;

         if (z = 3)
            code here;
    }

    if (buttonPressed)
    {
         code here;
    }

}
```

What do I put under if (y = 2) so that if its TRUE, it'll skip to the rest of of the "if (flagIsUp)" block (i.e. it will skip the "if (z = 3)" statement), and continue with the method (i.e. moving on to "if (buttonPressed)"? I tried break;, but that requires a loop. Using return; simply ends Method(), skipping through the rest of the code, which is not my intention.

Comment: Are `x`, `y` and `z` really separate variables?

Comment: this wont compile, you need == not = (comparison vs assignemnt)

Comment: It also won't compile because  "code here" is invalid code - I think this is pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

With the construct you've got, there's no easy keyword you can use. You should modify it to use `else`:

```
if (x = 1)
    code here;
else if (y = 2)
    code here;
else if (z = 3)
    code here;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, = assigns, == tests for equality.

That said, most of the time, including here, `else` should suffice:

```
if (y == 2)
    code here;
else if (z == 3)
    code here;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Method()
{
    if (flagIsUp)
    {
         if (x = 1)
         {
            code here;
         }  
         else if (y = 2)
         {
            code here;
         }
         else if (z = 3)
         {
            code here;
         }
    }

    if (buttonPressed)
    {
         code here;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers and explenations as to how they run in the back-end (as understanding the WHY will be helpful to you in the long run)

One simple answer put forth is to use `else` before each of the subsequent `if` statements like so

```
public void Method() 
{ 
    if (flagIsUp) 
    { 
         if (x == 1) 
            //code here; 

         else if (y == 2) 
            //code here; 

         else if (z == 3) 
            //code here; 
    } 

    if (buttonPressed) 
    { 
         //code here; 
    } 
}
```

What this ends up running like after compilation is more like

```
public void Method() 
{ 
    if (flagIsUp) 
    { 
         if (x == 1)
         {
            //code here; 
            // Excecution skips to 'x==1 fastforward'
         }
         else
         {
             if (y == 2) // intentional indentation
             {
                 //code here;
                 // Excecution skips to 'y==1 fastforward'
             } 
             else
             {
                 if (z == 3) // intentional indentation
                 {
                     //code here;
                 }
             } // y==2 fast forward
         } // x==1 fast forward
    } 

    if (buttonPressed) 
    { 
         code here; 
    } 
}
```

This arrangement shows how the if else if "indents" subroutines inside the conditional. If A is true, then it will skip the code for B and C all-together. If A is false, and B is true, C is skipped. If A and B are false C is checked.

Another way to accomplish this is to put this check into a private method of it's own and return from it when a true condition is met

```
public void Method() 
{ 
    if (flagIsUp)
        DoFlagUpCheck();

    if (buttonPressed) 
    { 
         //code here; 
    } 
} 

private void DoFlagUpCheck()
{
     if (x == 1) 
     {
        //code here; 
        return; // Stop and return to Method()
     }

     if (y == 2) 
     {
        //code here; 
        return; // Stop and return to Method()
     }

     if (z == 3) 
     {
        //code here; 
        return; // Stop and return to Method()
     }
}
```

This way, code execution stops and returns from the method on the first true condition. If A is true, do code and return, otherwise continue to B...

One thing worth considering is, can the program be refactored such that X, Y, and Z can be represented in a single enum? Since `x==1`, `y==2`, and `z==3` are mutually exclusive, there might be a way to make this set of conditions more readable and end up with something more like

```
public Method()
{
    if (flagIsUp)
    {
        switch(flagCondition)
        {
            case FlagX:
                //code here;
                break;
            case FlagY:
                //code here;
                break;
            case FlagZ:
                //Code here;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (buttonPressed)
    {
        //code here;
    }
}
```

Lastly, it's often helpful, for performance, to place the most likely true condition first.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want an else

```
if ( y == 2 ) { /* do stuff */ }
else if ( z == 3) { /* do other stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `else` in front of the `if`, but I'd recommend putting in the extra braces if you do.

```
public void Method()
{
    if (flagIsUp)
    {
         if (x == 1)
         {
            code here;
         }

         if (y == 2)
         {
            code here;
         }
         else if (z == 3)
         {
            code here;
         }
    }

    if (buttonPressed)
    {
         code here;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to a function:

```
if (flagIsUp)
{
   doStuff(x, y, z);
}

...

void doStuff(int x, int y, int z)
{
   if (x == 1)
   {
      // do stuff
      return;
   }
   if (y == 2)
   {
      // do stuff
      return;
   }
   if (z == 3)
   {
      // do stuff
      return;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a goto statement even if it is not good for code readability, could do do what you want ...

```
public void Method()
{
    if (flagIsUp)
    {
         if (x = 1)
            code here;

         if (y = 2){
            code here;
            goto Outer;
         }
         if (z = 3)
            code here;
    }

    Outer:
    if (buttonPressed)
    {
         code here;
    }

}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted. It's bad style as noted in the answer already, but it's a valid answer to the question that's asked.

Comment: you CAN use goto, but you REALLY REALLY REALLY shouldn't.

Comment: I think GOTO should be removed from .NET - there are always ways to make code ugly, but GOTO is the easiest of all. Then newbies wouldn't be taught bad style in the first place. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The answer is a simple else if, why use something bad as goto?

Comment: @Krumelur It has its uses. I fully agree that you shouldn't use it *in this case*, but `goto` remains appropriate in those cases where it simplifies the code by avoiding deeply nested conditions and unnecessary extra helper variables.

Comment: @Fox32 Because, even though else if answers the real question, "goto" answers what OP explicitly said, "*skip* rest of if statement".

Answer (score -1):

Use an `else` to accomlpish this

```
if (y == 2) {
  code1; 
} else{
  if (z == 3) {
    code2;
  } 
  code3;
}
```

Original code with my markers for clarity

```
if (y = 2)
  code1;

if (z = 3)
  code2;

code3;
```